# UIPageViewController loads wrong page

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a tutorial in my iOS app. But I have a bug in my PageViewController.

My tutorial has 5 pages. But the second movement that I do to change page always appears the previous page repeatedly.

For example, appears page0, move to page1, and then when i want to appear page2, appears page1 again.
This occurs to both sides.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 self.pageTexts = @[@"",intro1, intro2, intro3, intro4];

    self.index = 0;
    self.viewControllerPageContentOne = [[ViewControllerPageContentOne alloc] init];
    self.viewControllerPageContentTwo = [[ViewControllerPageContentTwo alloc] init];
    self.viewControllerPageContentThree = [[ViewControllerPageContentThree alloc] init];


    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;


    UIViewController* first = [self viewControllerUsed];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:first];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}




- (UIViewController *)viewControllerUsed{

    if (self.index == 0) {
        self.viewControllerPageContentOne=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentOne"];
        return self.viewControllerPageContentOne;
    }
    else if (self.index == 1)
    {
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"];
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo.titleText = self.pageTexts[self.index];
        return self.viewControllerPageContentTwo;
    }
    else if (self.index == 2)
    {
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"];
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo.titleText = self.pageTexts[self.index];
        return self.viewControllerPageContentTwo;
    }
    else if (self.index == 3)
    {
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"];
        self.viewControllerPageContentTwo.titleText = self.pageTexts[self.index];
        return self.viewControllerPageContentTwo;
    }
    else if (self.index == 4)

    {
        self.viewControllerPageContentThree=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentThree"];
        self.viewControllerPageContentThree.titleText = self.pageTexts[self.index];
        return self.viewControllerPageContentThree;
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }
}



#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    self.index--;
    if (self.index < 0) {
        self.index = [self.pageTexts count]-1;
    }
    return [self viewControllerUsed];


}



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    self.index++;
    if (self.index > [self.pageTexts count]-1) {
        self.index = 0;
    }
    return [self viewControllerUsed];

}





- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageTexts count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

I suppose that there is an error in index pages but I don’t know it.
Thanks

Comment: Did you notice that in your `viewControllerUsed` for index 1, 2 & 3 you are returning same view controller object with different title. Is that expected?

Comment: Your viewControllerUsed method is returning the same view controller for indices 1-3, which might explain what you're seeing. Try changing that to return a different view controller.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is that screens with index 1,2,3 is the same view but with different title or text

Comment: Could be this the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are creating class level properties for view controllers. And that too you are initialising them in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.viewControllerPageContentOne = [[ViewControllerPageContentOne alloc] init];
self.viewControllerPageContentTwo = [[ViewControllerPageContentTwo alloc] init];
self.viewControllerPageContentThree = [[ViewControllerPageContentThree alloc] init];
```

My advise is to create view controllers and save them in an array like this:

```
UIViewController *page0 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentOne"];

UIViewController *page1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"]
page3.titleText = self.pageTexts[1];

UIViewController *page2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"]
page3.titleText = self.pageTexts[2];

UIViewController *page3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentTwo"]
page3.titleText = self.pageTexts[3];

UIViewController *page4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerPageContentThree"];

[self.viewControllers addObject:page0];
[self.viewControllers addObject:page1];
[self.viewControllers addObject:page2];
[self.viewControllers addObject:page3];
[self.viewControllers addObject:page4];
```

And then in your `viewControllerUsed` simply return viewControllers from `self.viewControllers` like `self.viewControllers[self.index]`.